# Вопрос по Pygame. Синхронизация событий по времени

Tags: python, pygame

```
def draw_pixel(position):
    global SIZE
    global COLOR
    SCREEN.fill(COLOR, (position, SIZE))


while True:  # main loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            FLAG = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            FLAG = False
    if FLAG:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        draw_pixel(pos)
    change_brush_size_button.draw_button()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Обычная рисовалка. Зажал левую кнопку - рисуешь линию в один пиксель. Но линия получается отрывистая, потому что, как я понял, между получением текущей позиции мыши и отрисовкой пикселя проходит некоторое время. Возможно, я ошибаюсь в причине, но всё же мне думается, что надо как-то всё это дело правильно привязать ко времени. Когда речь идёт о перемещении спрайта персонажа в игре, то я понимаю, как это сделать. Там просто надо обновлять время в начале каждого цикла и умножать время на скорость персонажа. Но вот тут я что-то запутался. 
Я знаю, что вместо отрисовки отдельных пикселей можно рисовать линии (pygame.draw.line()). Но мне это в данной ситуации не подходит. Нужно сделать плавной и непрерывной отрисовку отдельных пикселей, если это возможно. В итоге из этого должен получиться редактор для пиксель-арт графики, поэтому мне важен контроль над отдельными пикселями. 
Может кто-нибудь подсказать, в каком направлении мне копать?

Comment: Наверное, после установки флага нажатия клавиши надо ловить событие перемещения мыши, если такое имеется.

Comment: А смысл? Есть событие MOUSEMOTION, но оно же говорит о самом факте, что мышь была передвинута. Мне в любом случае надо успевать ловить все координаты, где побывала мышь, чтобы успеть их все отрисовать

Comment: Что подразумевается под всеми координатами? Траектория мыши с дискретом в один пиксель? А если попробовать начать с линейной интерполяции между точками, которые возвращает `MOUSEMOTION`?

Comment: Под всеми координатами подразумевается то, что мне придётся хранить массив пикселей для каждого слоя, так как это растровый редактор, ориентированный на пиксель-арт. Каждый кадр состоит из нескольких слоёв, на каждом из которых отрисованы пиксели, и все их позиции и цвета нужно хранить в памяти. Если я буду использовать линии, то потом придётся проходить по всей поверхности попиксельно, чтобы заполнить массив (или список, или что-то ещё), хранящий растр.

Comment: Ну, вообще, да, "траектория мыши с дискретом в один пиксель" - наверное, более точное и понятное описание того, что мне нужно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, решение нашёл сам. Может, это топорно и велосипедно, но работает так, как мне было нужно изначально. Нагуглил алгоритм рисования линии, перепилил его на Python. Теперь я рисую линиями, но имею контроль над отрисовкой каждого отдельного пикселя. Алгоритм называется “Алгоритм Брезенхэма”, если кому будет интересно или нужно.

```
def draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    delta_x = abs(x2 - x1)
    delta_y = abs(y2 - y1)
    if x1 < x2:
        sign_x = 1
    else:
        sign_x = -1
    if y1 < y2:
        sign_y = 1
    else:
        sign_y = -1

    error = delta_x - delta_y

    draw_pixel([x2, y2])
    while (x1 != x2 or y1 != y2): 
        draw_pixel([x1, y1])
        error_2 = error * 2

        if error_2 > -delta_y: 
            error -= delta_y
            x1 += sign_x

        if error_2 < delta_x:
            error += delta_x
            y1 += sign_y


while True:  # main loop
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            FLAG = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            FLAG = False

    if FLAG:
       new_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
       draw_line(pos[0], pos[1], new_pos[0], new_pos[1])

    pygame.display.flip()
```